# Fragment ViewBinding Object always null inside interface callback

Tags: android, android-fragments, interface, android-viewbinding

I am trying to access the view-binding object of a fragment inside an interface callback but the state of the binding object is always null when the callback is triggered from the parent activity.

ParentActivity.class (Interface callback trigger)

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SimpleSearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onQueryTextSubmit: "+query);
                listener.loadQuery(query); // Triggers interface callback
                return true;
            }
});
```

ChildFragment.class (Interface callback)

```
@Override
 public void loadQuery(String query) {
  // Callback received
  Log.d(TAG, "binding: "+ (bindingChildFragment != null)); //always false
  Log.d(TAG, "binding obj: "+ bindingChildFragment); //always null
}
```

The binding was initialized inside *onCreateView* of the fragment and it works as expected in all area but always null inside the interface callback. What must i be missing?

Comment: Have you implement your listener in child fragment? Like childfragment implemens listnername.

Comment: Yes, i implemented the listener on the fragment that is why the method "loadQuery" could be overridden

Comment: Need more code like how you're setting up interface between activity and fragment and also how you're setting up ViewBinding. @GiddyNaya